# Cypress: How to call a parameter from a previous custom command into a new custom command?

Tags: cypress

I have a command that will carry out a process and it will use a previous command to get the numbers it requires, however as I have not explicitly called the orderNumber so I am getting an error.

```
Cypress.Commands.add('cancelOrder', () => {

 // Search for the order number
cy.get('#OrderNumberField').type(orderNumber);
...
}
```

How would I write the command to not get any errors under 'orderNumber'? The test will pass as it should use the order number from a previous command that I will add to the test but as the command, before it might change depending on the item ordered, I don't want to add it all into one command.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your test looks something like

```js
cy.getOrderNumber().cancelOrder()
```

then we can simply change the two commands to yield and take in the order number.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('getOrderNumber', () => {
  // whatever code is needed to get the order number
  return orderNumber
})

Cypress.Commands.add('cancelOrder', { prevSubject: true }, (orderNumber) => {
  cy.get('#OrderNumberField').type(orderNumber)
});
```

We're able to do this because we're designating `cy.cancelOrder()` as a [child command.](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands#Child-Commands)